# Reshape a 3D array and remove missing values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, nan, reshape

I have an NxMxT array where each element of the array is a grid of Earth. If the grid is over the ocean, then the value is 999. If the grid is over land, it contains an observed value. N is longitude, M is latitude, and T is months.
In particular, I have an array called `tmp60` for the ten years 1960 through 1969, so 120 months for each grid.

To test what the global mean in January 1960 was, I write:

```
tmpJan60=tmp60(:,:,1);
tmpJan60(tmpJan60(:,:)>200)=NaN;
nanmean(nanmean(tmpJan60))
```

which gives me 5.855.

**I am confused about the reshape function.** I thought the following code should yield the same average, namely 5.855, but it does not:

```
load tmp60

N1=size(tmp60,1)
N2=size(tmp60,2)
N3=size(tmp60,3)

reshtmp60 = reshape(tmp60, N1*N2,N3);
reshtmp60( reshtmp60(:,1)>200,: )=[];
mean(reshtmp60(:,1))
```

this gives me -1.6265, which is not correct.

I have checked the result in Excel (!) and 5.855 is correct, so I assume I make a mistake in the reshape function.

Ideally, I want a matrix that takes each grid, going first down the N-dimension,  and make the 720 rows with 120 columns (each column is a month). These first 720 rows will represent one longitude band around Earth for the same latitude. Next, I want to increase the latitude by 1, thus another 720 rows with 120 columns. Ultimately I want to do this for all 360 latitudes. 
If longitude and latitude were inputs, say column 1 and 2, then the matrix should look like this:

```
temp = [-179.75 -89.75 -1  2 ...
        -179.25 -89.75 2  4 ...
           ...
         179.75 -89.75 5 9 ...
        -179.75 -89.25 2  5 ...
        -179.25 -89.25 3  4 ... 
          ...
        -179.75  89.75 2  3 ...
          ...
         179.75  89.75 6  9 ...]
```

So `temp(:,3)` should be all January 1960 observations.

One way to do this is:

```
grid1 = tmp60(1,1,:);
g1 = reshape(grid1, [1,120]);
grid2 = tmp60(2,1,:);
g2 = reshape(grid2,[1,120]);
g = [g1;g2];
```

But obviously very cumbersome.

I am not able to automate this procedure for the N*M elements, so comments are appreciated!

[A link to the file tmp60.mat](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bw03U0rliS5PUnpIZmVUbUFCc0k?usp=sharing)

Comment: You show reshtemp1 and reshtmp60, is this a typo? ... what does reshtemp1 equal?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Sure, and I understand that N is longitude, but what is N1, N2, N3?

Comment: Also, shouldn't mean(reshtmp60(:,1)) be mean(reshtmp60(:,3))... the same column that you just removed the Nan's (999) from?

Comment: N1=720, N2=360, N3=120

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, but what I would do is go through and check each line.
Once you reshape, what is the size of reshtmp60? 
Then do reshtmp60( reshtmp60(:,1)>200)=NaN; And check how manyNan's are there with sum(isnan(reshtmp60)).  If that give 10, then after reshtmp60( reshtmp60(:,1)>200)=[]; (OR reshtmp60( isnan(reshtmp60))=[]) , length(reshtmp60) should be 120-10 = 110.

Comment: The code does not give an error message, but I do not understand why the first two code-snippets give two different answers. The size is: size(reshtmp60) = [67420, 120]

Comment: Ok, so N1*N2 is 259200, so your size should be 259200 x 120. Why are you getting 67420? Is it because that is the size once you removed NaN's? You should also set reshtmp60 to a new variable before removing NaN's, because that will automatically reshape your matrix, if the NaN's are at the end.

Comment: Yes, before removing the NaN's the size is 259200x120, and after it is 67420x120.

Comment: Which is most likely why you are getting a different mean, because your matrix is being reshaped when you remove([]) values. If you can keep NaN's there, that is the best way to use matlab, especially with lat/lon coordinates, because you want your matrix to always be the same size. Is there a reason why you don't want to work with NaN's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is treating the `nan`s. Observe the following example:

```
a = randi(10,6);
a(a>7)=nan
m = [mean(a(:),'omitnan') mean(mean(a,'omitnan'),'omitnan')]

m =
       3.8421       3.6806
```

Both elements in `m` are simply the mean on all elements in `a`. But they are different! The reason is the taking the mean of all values together, with `mean(a(:),'omitnan')` is like summing all not-nan values, and divide by the number of values we summed:

```
sum(a(:),'omitnan')/sum(~isnan(a(:)))==mean(a(:),'omitnan') % this is true
```

but taking the mean of the first dimension, we get 6 mean values:

```
sum(a,'omitnan')./sum(~isnan(a))==mean(a,'omitnan') % this is also true
```

and when we take the mean of them we divide by a larger number, because all `nan`s were omitted already:

```
mean(sum(a,'omitnan')./sum(~isnan(a)))==mean(a(:),'omitnan') % this is false
```

---

Here is what I think you want in your code:

```
% this is exactly as your first test:
tmpJan60=tmn60(:,:,1);
tmpJan60(tmpJan60>200) = nan;
m1 = mean(mean(tmpJan60,'omitnan'),'omitnan')

% this creates the matrix as you want it:
result = reshape(permute(tmn60,[3 1 2]),120,[]).';
result(result>200) = nan;
r = reshape(result(:,1),720,360);
m2 = mean(mean(r,'omitnan'),'omitnan')

isequal(m1,m2)
```

To create the matrix you first permute the dimensions so the one you want to keep as is (time) will be the first. Then reshape the array to Tx(lon*lat), so you get 120 rows for all time steps and 259200 columns for all combinations of the coordinates. All that's left is to transpose it.

`m1` is your first calculation, and `m2` is what you try to do in the second one. They are equal here, but their value is not 5.855, even if I use your code.

However, I think the right solution will be to take the mean of all values together:

```
mean(result(:,1),'omitnan')
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much!